# Limiting job for some months to manager

Tags: professionalism, ethics

I am working as software technical consultant and my job description is to become pre-sales and delivery. Pre-sales is the one who meet new prospect, do demo and POC create proposal, while delivery is the one who do the real project.

My division only consists of 2 people (me and my colleague) and I always the one who do the pre-sales.

As we are going to have some projects in upcoming 2-3 months, is it professional if now I tell my manager that I don't want to do the pre-sales until all projects are settled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, "I don't want" is never professional. To a large extent, you're at work to do what your employer wants, not what you want. The way to start this discussion is to go to your manager and explain why it would be better *for the company* if you finished your project work first before moving onto pre-sales.

Comment: Not true... I'm at work for the free tea and coffee

Comment: While you can and should explain the risks of moving to presales while there are still projects to do, don;t expect them to be very agreeable. Without the pre-sales, they have no new customers in the pipeline and they may  feel that is critical to company success, more so than delays in the existing projects. A better suggestion might be to work half time on each until you finish your assigned project tasks. And do not take on any tasks you have not already been assigned. Project work is no longer your job.